# Scrapy DOWNLOAD_DELAY not working for sequential requets

Tags: python, api, scrapy, fitbit

I am currently working with the Scrapy Python library.

First I make a FormRequest call to the Fitbit's login page (https://www.fitbit.com/login) to log myself in. Then I make close to 100 requests to the Fitbit's API (https://api.fitbit.com).

To not stress out the API (and to not get banned from it!), I wanted to set a delay between the requests using DOWNLOAD_DELAY in the settings.py file. However it is not working.

I was testing it in the tutorials (http://scrapy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html) and it was working properly there.

What do you think? Is it because I request an API (supposed to handle those kinds of accesses)?

EDIT: here is the pseudo code of my spider:

```
class FitbitSpider:
    start_urls = ["https://www.fitbit.com/login"]

    def parse(self, response):
        yield scrapy.FormRequest(url,formdata,callback=after_login)

    def after_login(self, response):
        for i in range(100):
            yield scrapy.Request("https://api.fitbit.com/[...]")
```

EDIT 2: here is my settings.py file:

```
BOT_NAME = 'fitbitscraper'

SPIDER_MODULES = ['fitbitscraper.spiders']
NEWSPIDER_MODULE = 'fitbitscraper.spiders'

DOWNLOAD_DELAY = 20 #20 seconds of delay should be pretty noticeable
```

Comment: what tutorial ? What code did you test? Better show real code, not pseudo code, if you don't need pseudo solutions.

Comment: http://scrapy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html. The scraping is working properly, unless the delay is not observed. And since the code is 300 lines long, I cannot give it here (it would be irrelevant to the topic as well, I believe).

Comment: Please show your `settings.py`. Also, how did you find out it was not working? It's best to provide complete information.

Comment: @Xema how do you know the `DOWNLOAD_DELAY` is not working? is it between `www.fitbit.com` and `api.fitbit.com` requests? are you doing requests to another domain apart from those 2?

Comment: @Thomas Linhart. I provided the settings.py file, which is pretty simple as you can see. For me it is not working since I do not notice the 20s delays between the requests.
@ eLRuLL only one request to www.fitbit.com and 300 to api.fitbit.com.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Alright, I just found the answer to my problem.

It came from the creation of a CrawlerProcess in the main.py file I was running. It did not load the settings in the settings.py file.

Beforehand I was doing the following:

```
process = CrawlerProcess({
    'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1)'
})

process.crawl(fitbit_spider.FitbitSpider)
process.start()
```

Now if I change the CrawlerProcess into:

```
process = CrawlerProcess({
        'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1)',
        'DOWNLOAD_DELAY': 20
})
```

I do get the wanted delay !

Note: using `get_project_settings()` to create the CrawlerProcess is not working either.

Answer (score 8):

According to [the documentation](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#download-delay):

> **DOWNLOAD_DELAY:** The amount of time (in secs) that the downloader should wait before downloading consecutive pages from the same
>   website. This can be used to throttle the crawling speed to avoid
>   hitting servers too hard.

As we can see there, this configuration only affects **consecutive pages from the same website**, and that is because of the assigned `slots` of the crawler. By default, `scrapy` sets a slot per domain (because the idea is that every slot should handle its own speed).

Now, you can also change on which `slot` a request could be handled with the `meta` variable `download_slot`, so make sure you are not playing with that variable if you don't know what it could do.

Also other settings can interfere with `DOWNLOAD_DELAY` like:

- [`CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_IP`](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#concurrent-requests-per-ip)
- [`RANDOMIZE_DOWNLOAD_DELAY`](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#randomize-download-delay)
- [`AUTOTHROTTLE_ENABLED`](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/autothrottle.html)

So make sure they are not enabled, or you are not trying to use both settings on the same project.

Also it is important to point-out that `download_delay` can also be enabled as a `Spider` variable, and that it takes precedence over the one inside Settings.